# EF PK FK mapping without scalar PK properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Is it posible to define a compound foreign primary key without defining scalar properties?

```
public class A 
{
  public virtual int AID { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public virtual int BID { get; set; }
}

public class CompoundKeyClass
{
  public virtual A AObject { get; set; }
  public virtual B BObject { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make properties AObject and BObject the compound PK of CompoundKeyClass without defining the scalar ID properties of for A and B types using the FluentAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Both `AID` and `BID` must be in your `CompoundKeyClass` mapped as complex primary key and each of them must be mapped as foreign key to related table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was afraid this was going to be case.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can't; the closest I can find to documentation on this is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx):

> ***KeyAttribute***
>
> KeyAttribute is used to specify that a property/column is part of the primary key of the entity and applies to scalar properties only.

You should, however, be able to name the foreign key properties "_AID" and "_BID", and/or mark them as `[Browsable(false)]`. This should ensure you cannot use or even see them accidentally.